# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, class, core-bluetooth, ambiguous

I have this block of code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

public class Service {

    static var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    private init() {}

    public static func doSomething() {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

}
```

But on building, it says that I have the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` in the one line in my doSomthing() func. What could be the cause of this and how can I get this small class to build and run?

Comment: You don't have a `self` in a class method. I guess that's the main issue. You might be interested by the Singleton Pattern (usually named sharedInstance/shared in Swift).

Comment: So should I make another class to be the delegate class for CBCentralManager?

Answer (score 0):

To be a CBCentralDelegate you need to a) be an NSObject subclass and b) actually implement the required protocol method.  You also should make a shared instance that wraps the centralManager and exposes only your interface.

```
public class Service: NSObject {
    static let shared = Service()
    private lazy var centralManager: CBCentralManager = {
        return CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public static func doSomething() {
        //Do things with centralManager here
    }
}

extension Service: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    }
}
```

call singleton with:

```
Service.shared.doSomething()
```

Comment: That makes sense. But I am writing this as a a part of a library / cocoapod so when I try to call doSomething() as you said to, it tells me `shared is inaccessible due to internal protection level`

Comment: then make it public static let shared = Service()